# Why am I getting a return value of zero from my position computation function?

Tags: xna-4.0, mouse

Ok I have a Function int x(), which is used in

```
new Rectangle(x(),a,a,a);
```

in DrawMethod in XNA
but when I use it I get x() = 0 as as the answer.Here is my CODE:

```
int x()
        {
            int px = (128 * 5);
            int xx = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {

                if (Mouse.GetState().X > px)
                {
                    //xx = Mouse.GetState().X;
                    xx = px;
                    break;
                }
                else
                { px -= 128; }
            }

            return xx;
        }
```

Here is the DrawMethod Code:

```
if (set)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle(x(), y(), texture.Width, texture.Height), Color.White);
            textpositionX = x();
            textpositionY = y();
            set = false;
            select = false;
            place = true;

        }
        else if(select)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle(Mouse.GetState().X - texture.Width / 2, Mouse.GetState().Y-texture.Height / 2, texture.Width, texture.Height), Color.White);

        }
        else if (place)
        { spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle(textpositionX, textpositionY, texture.Width, texture.Height), Color.White);
        select = false;
        set = false;
        }
```

Comment: Could you show us the body of your function `x()`?

Comment: Have you tried debugging using breakpoints? Which parts are unexpected? Does `x` work if you replace Mouse.GetState() by a dummy test value (such as `123`)?

Comment: While debugging I dont get Mouse.getstate().X value...after debugging the x(), x is equal to zero, I dont know why??

Comment: oh and I am getting Mouse.getstate().X negative...

Comment: Negative positions are possible "f the mouse is to the left of the client area (the inside portion of the game window, excluding the borders), the returned coordinate is negative." (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.mousestate.x.aspx )

Comment: On a sidenote, finding xx iteratively is wasteful when you could do it in one line something like floor(Mouse.GetState().X/128)*128

Answer (score 1):

One useful debugging technique to determine why some particular behavior is happening is to work backwards from that behavior's observable effect. In this case, the effect is that `x()` returns 0. So let's examine `x`:

- `x` only has one return statement, so that's the only place you can be returning zero. The value returned is the variable `xx`.
- `xx` is a local, and receives a value in two places in the code. First, it receives a value of zero upon initialization. Second, it receives the value of `px` upon taking the positive branch of your `if` statement. If you never take that positive branch, you'll never modify `xx` and thus will return 0.
- So, is it possible that you never take that positive branch? The condition is that the mouse's X position is greater than `px`, which starts at 640 and decreases by 128 five times (so the final value of `px` is 0). So you'll never take that branch if the mouse's X position is negative, which as was pointed out in the comments, [is totally possible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.mousestate.x.aspx).

Consequently, we can conclude that your function is returning zero because the mouse is off the left edge of the client area when you run it.

Comment: Wouldn't it return 0 under for all cases where the mouse was to the left of the left side + 640 pixels?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you are asking? Do you mean it would return zero if the mouse X is less than 640 pixels? Or less than -640 pixels?

Comment: I belive it would return 0 for all cases where (mouse.x < (window.bounds.left + 640)).

Comment: How so? I read it as: if X is 500 then the code runs through the for loop once, and takes the negative branch of the "if" (px is 640, 500 > 640 is false), subtracting 128 from px (it's now 512). It will go through the loop again, again taking the negative branch (500 > 512 is false), subtracting 128 from px again (it's now 384). It goes through a third iteration, but now it takes the positive branch (500 > 384 is true), sets xx to px (xx is now 384) and breaks the loop. Then xx is returned, so the result is 384. X is always relative to the upper left of the window.

Comment: Yeah you're correct, I somehow completly skipped over the "px -= 128;" part.